# The particular approximation of a function

Tags: functions, approximation

Suppose the function

```
f[x_,y_] := P[x/y]*Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2] + F[x/y]*Log[(1-Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2])/(1+Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2])]
```

Here $P[x,y], F[x,y]$ are polynomial of some definite degree in the argument $x/y$.

My question is, whether some manipulation exists providing "smart" manipulation with $f[x,y]$ which neglect positive degrees of $x/y$ inside $P,F$ (say, assuming it to be small), but leaving the argument of the logarithm completely unchanged?

For specific example, assume

```
f[x_,y_] := (a+b*x/y + c*x/y^2)*Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2] + (d + e*x/y + f*x^2/y^2)*Log[(1-Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2])/(1+Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2])]
```

I need the following output after the manipulation:

```
f[x_,y_] := a + d*Log[(1-Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2])/(1+Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2])]
```

Comment: A more concrete demonstration might be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by neglect?

Comment: @Andrew : I've added an example.

Comment: @Andrew : I want to set them to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one logarithm, as in your example, this will do:

```
g[x_,y_]=f[x, y] /. Log[A_] :> (B = A; C) /. x -> 0 /. C -> Log[B]
```

Comment: sorry, couly you please explain briefly what does this code mean?

Comment: First `Log[A]` changed on symbol `C`, then `x` is put to zero - it will nullify all the terms you want. Finally `C` is changed back to `Log[A]`. it is assumed here that symbols `A`, `B`, `C` are not used in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you also please help me how to remain unchanged both the logarithm and the square root in the front of P[x,y] in my example? Add 
$$
\text{Log[A_] -> (B = A; C) && Sqrt[1-x^2/y^2] -> (B1 = A1; C1)}
$$
instead of
$$
\text{Log[A_] -> (B = A; C),}
$$
right?

Comment: {Log[A_] :> (B = A; C), Sqrt[A1_] :> (B1 = A1; C1)}